# Gradle Incremental Java build fails with “cannot find Symbol error”

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin, incremental-build

Build is failing when I did a change in Java file

Android Gradle Plugin: 3.2.1
Gradle Version: 4.6

Please find the snapshot of error below:

```
17:58:31.131 [ERROR] [system.err] symbol: class FragmentNavigationManager
17:58:31.132 [ERROR] [system.err] location: package com.microsoft.office.officemobile.FragmentManagerInfra
17:58:31.138 [ERROR] [system.err] D:\Office\dev\officemobile\android\Java\src\com\microsoft\office\officemobile\ActionsTab\ActionsAdapter.java:45: error: cannot find symbol
17:58:31.138 [ERROR] [system.err] import com.microsoft.office.officemobile.KaizalaPhoneauth.KaizalaPhoneAuthManager;
```

I checked the undefined symbols are present inside file FragmentNavigationManager.java file inside the sources.

Using debug logs, I found the class file `FragmentNavigationManager.class` is getting deleted before doing java build

```
gradle: 17:58:28.630 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.file.delete.Deleter] Deleting d:\office\build\droidarm\ship\officemobile\android\java\intermediates\javac\release\compileReleaseJavaWithJavac\classes\com\microsoft\office\officemobile\FragmentManagerInfra\FragmentNavigationManager.class
```

After deletion of above class, while doing Java incremental build, `FragmentNavigationManager.java` should be passed as an input for javac, but it is not happening, which is causing undefined symbol issue. Clean build working fine

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue
The source file path is: src\com\microsoft\office\officemobile*fragmentmanagerinfra*\FragmentNavigationManager.java

Generated Class file: intermediates\javac\release\compileReleaseJavaWithJavac\classes\com\microsoft\office\officemobile*FragmentManagerInfra*\FragmentNavigationManager.class

There is a case mismatch in directory name at source path and generated class path, which is causing the issue. Source path has fragmentnavigationmanager instead of FragmentNavigationManager

I found that the package name is: com.microsoft.office.officemobile.FragmentManagerInfra.FragmentNavigationManager. Changing directory name to match the package name at the source path resolves the issue

Is this expected, as full build is working fine and incremental Gradle build is only failing?
Working on Windows 10